# Python: ImportError while __init__.py exists

Tags: python, flask

I have the file: run.py in `C:/mycp/applicationl` directory, which contains the following code:

```
from che import wserver
from applicationl import app
```

The directory: `C:/mycp/applicationl` also contains the `__init__.py` file.

When I run `python run.py`, It gives me the following error:

```
  File "run.py", line 8, in <module>
    from application1 import app
ImportError: No module named 'application1'
```

But `__init__.py` exists, and app exists in this file:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is `c:\mycp\application1` in your python path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not run file as a script *and* expect the directory to be treated as a package.

For `applicationl` to be treated as a package, the *parent* directory has to be added to the Python `sys.path` module lookup path. But when you run a script, the directory itself is added instead.

It is not a good idea to manually add the `C:/mycp` directory to `sys.path`. Just import other Python code as top-level modules here instead, *or* create a subdirectory of `C:/mycp/applicationl` and use that as a package instead.

Without creating additional packages, your `run.py` code should change to:

```
from che import wserver
from app import app
```

and rename `__init__.py` to `app.py`.

Alternatively, create a new subdirectory; it can even be named `applicationl` *again*, and move `__init__` into that subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside `C:/mycp/applicationl`you can't import from `application1` if it isn't in your `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `from . import app` since `app.py` is in same folder as `run.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'C:/mycp/application1' to the environment variable PYTHONPATH